# Maximum RAM for an Asus Motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard, gaming

I have an MX Asus motherboard with a p4-400w power supply, a GTX 650 graphics card, a 160 GB hard drive  and 2GB RAM DDR2 in total. I am running Windows 7 Professional.My processor is up to 2.00 GHz and my system rating is a 5.0.

I can play Counter Strike Global Offence easily on medium settings I recently saw a few games like RUST and Blackwake that I want to play them but I require 8 GB of RAM minimum.

Now what I am asking is how much RAM can I put into this pc?

In some cases I see the max is 2 GB but other forums say some manufacturers are somewhat wrong and this can be increased.

Comment: While this question does not exactly seek a hardware shopping recommendation, I'm voting to close it as such because (like those questions) it's "relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly".

Comment: hi and thank you i just have 1 more thing to ask if  i was able to get lets say 2 x 2 GB ram's total of 4 GB or 2 x 4 GB rams total 8 GB ram's what will happen to my pc will it not boot up or will it only use the 2 GB limit thank you

Comment: I have attempted to clarify your question to prevent it attracting any more negative feedback. I strongly suggest you read [ask] and take our [tour]. This isn't a traditional forum and follows different rules. Also please include the exact model number of your motherboard.

Comment: **It won't support more than 2GB total nor even a single module larger than 1GB**, it won't boot with more and such old hardware (motherboard) may fry if you try it. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 2):

No, the manufacturer's specifications are what matters, not what random people in online forums say, including me :).

As you can see at [ASUS P5GC-MX specifications page](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/P5GCMX/specifications/) it is indeed limited to *2 x DIMM, Max. **2 GB**, DDR2 533/400 Non-ECC,Un-buffered Memory*. On top of that, even if the motherboard could support more, the CPU wouldn't.

It must be said that you can still find this type of RAM but it can be quite expensive comparatively.

Your PC is old and *de facto* obsolete for gaming. It may still have some usage if refitted with a (light) Linux distro (e.g. Lubuntu or Xubuntu). The standard Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu Gnome, etc., or even Ubuntu MATE may work but will poor performance, predictably worse than Windows 7.